# golang - weird characters using io.Copy to copy from bufio.Reader to STDOUT

Tags: go, docker, io, stdout

I have an application that attaches to a docker container to get its output using the [containerAttach()](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/client#Client.ContainerAttach) function provided by the docker library.
That function returns a [HijackedResponse](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/api/types#HijackedResponse) struct with a pointer to a bufio.Reader.

I'm trying to stream text from the bufio.Reader to stdout and getting unexpected characters in the strings written to stdout.

The code:

```
_, err := io.Copy(os.Stdout, hijackedResponse.Reader)
```

Expected output:

```
Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but
will not be persisted to local or remote state storage.
```

Actual output:

```
6Refreshing Terraform state in-memory prior to plan...
=The refreshed state will be used to calculate this plan, but
9will not be persisted to local or remote state storage.
```

I have no idea where the first character in each of those lines has come from. Any help would be much appreciated. If needed I can provide more details around the docker container & attach options I'm using in my code although I'm assuming they're fine as I'm getting the output via the reader.

Comment: The lines are prefixed with a byte containing the count of the remaining bytes on the line.  The io.Copy function and os.Stdout don't do anything that will add these bytes.

Comment: thanks @CeriseLimón but do you have any suggestions on a nice clean way to prevent that byte from being displayed in my output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem - my [containerConfig](https://godoc.org/github.com/docker/docker/api/types/container#Config) needed to specify `Tty: true`